# Apache Camel Unmarshal to Singleton Scoped Bean

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm using Spring as my Bean registry and I currently have a route defined with the Java DSL as follows:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
   from("netty:tcp://{{netty.host}}:{{netty.port}}?sync=false")
         .routeId("pbxToBean").unmarshal("castor").to("mock:result");
}
```

It takes an XML marshaled input from a Netty endpoint and unmarshalls it to a PBX bean.

I was thinking I could declare my result PBX bean as a Singleton and have Camel pass an unmarshalled object to a Processor which then updates said singleton bean. Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if casor is a bean bound in the registry,

```
/**
 * <a href="http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html">DataFormat:</a>
 * Unmarshals the in body using the specified {@link DataFormat}
 * reference in the {@link org.apache.camel.spi.Registry} and sets
 * the output on the out message body.
 *
 * @param dataTypeRef  reference to a {@link DataFormat} to lookup in the registry
 * @return the builder
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Type unmarshal(String dataTypeRef) {
    addOutput(new UnmarshalDefinition(dataTypeRef));
    return (Type) this;
}
```

Comment: So right now, Castor is defined as a data format within the camel-spring context xml. As it stands right now, each unmarshalled object creates a new instance an unmarshalled bean instead of using a singleton. How would I go about redefining Castor from a data format to a singleton bean?

Comment: Sorry, now Im actually not sure if i understood you correctly in your first question. But http://camel.apache.org/castor.html <dataFormats>
    <castor id="myCastor"/>
  </dataFormats> then you can use unmarshal("myCastor"), but I guess you could also do <bean id="myCastor" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.castor.CastorDataFormat" />

Comment: It's currently set up exactly as described, actually. The thing is, the resulting POJO is a new instance of said POJO and not a singleton.